# Asking for READ_SMS asks for "send and view SMS messages"

Tags: android, permissions, sms, android-6.0-marshmallow

My app needs to use a "READ_SMS" permission only.
My problem is that on Android 6.0 When I need to use the new permission system it asks a "send and view SMS messages" from the user.

This is my code:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, READ_SMS_PERMISION_REQ);
```

What is going on?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is going on?

It is working as expected.

While we request permissions via `requestPermissions()`, the user accepts or denies permission *groups*. So, if your array had `READ_SMS` and `SEND_SMS`, despite having two permissions, the user would only have to accept one thing in the runtime permission dialog. Or, if you only had `READ_SMS` here (and the user grants the permission), but then later called `checkSelfPermission()` for `SEND_SMS`, you would be told that you have it, as the user granted the whole SMS permission group.

The downside is that the permission groups often cover read and write permissions, so even if you only ask for read, the user is told that you might write.

My guess is that the objective was to keep the granularity of accept/deny decisions down. The fact that `requestPermissions()` takes permissions, not groups, means that Google has the right to change its mind in future versions of Android, if this read vs. write issue becomes a problem for users or developers.

Comment: It sure is a problem! But i'm not sure I am reading it as you are... It says "READ_SMS and SEND_SMS" not READ_SMS or SEND_SMS. So, only if you do both it should sow this message.  My app only needs to read an SMS for registration, why show a write SMS to the user? It's crazy!

Comment: So, Just to understand... They will always show Grouped messages? 
It's insane.

Comment: @roiberg: "They will always show Grouped messages?" -- this is the way it is for Android 6.0, at least in the current developer preview. Bear in mind that this is similar to what the user has seen for the past two years or so on the Play Store. For example, if I click "Install" for Go SMS Pro, I am told that it "Uses one or more of: SMS, MMS. Charges may apply." It does not indicate read or write capability. Only if the user clicks on the "Permissions" link do they get the full details, and that should be unchanged with Android 6.0.

Comment: In my opinion saying "SMS" with an option to see what about this SMS is 10 times better than saying "Read and Write" without option to see witch of them.
Ohh, when I said "always" I didn't mean in the future, I meant in all cases. Does it show a grouped messages in all cases as of today.

Comment: @roiberg: "Does it show a grouped messages in all cases as of today" -- yes. Users grant permission groups, and so the messaging will be by the group. Each group will have both read and write permissions, in cases where write permissions exist. The permission groups shifted a bit; you can see the Android 6.0 lineup in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html#permission-groups).

Comment: Thanks! This is stupid!! It could be much better if we had the controll of what to ask. But it's not your fault :)

Answer (score 0):

I am use this

```
 if (BuildUtil.isAndroidM()) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PermissionUtil.sms(),
                    PermissionUtil.PERMISSION_SMS);
        } else {
            // TODO
        }
    } else {
        // TODO
    }
```

Comment: It's pointless...  On versions lower than M nothing will happen when you ask for permissions... They just jump to the callback